# how to get the base-hostename (blog name) with tumblr api after a successfull oauth-authorization

Tags: ruby, api, oauth, tumblr

I have a tumblr api-application and i need to receive infos about a specific blog.
To get this information I need the following request:

```
api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/info?api_key={key}
```

But I don't know how i get the {base-hostname} from the user who is logged in. Oauth provides just the conusmer-key, the consumer-secret, theo auth-token, and the oauth-token-secret. But i need the blog-name which matches with the user credentials. It works perfectly fine with the tumblr_client gem but due to some reason I am not allowed to use ist. 
Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can parse the response from `/user/info` api (which is based on oauth creds provided for the request). It returns the `name / url` for the user's blog(s), which you can then use in your {base-hostname}.

Comment: this worked perfectly fine, i just had to make a get request `test=@access_token.get("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info")`
`credentials = JSON::parse(test.body)`
`puts credentials`